# Using Celery in Flask causes warning: MongoClient opened before fork

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, celery

When I use Celery-schedule task in Flask to save data from redis to mongoDB, Celery raises a warning message:

```
[2021-07-11 17:01:19,092: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] 
/home/moluo/anaconda3/envs/mofang/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/pymongo/topology.py:161: UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. 
Create MongoClient only after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for 
details: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe
```

The code leading to the warning:

```
import orjson
from application import celery,redis_tree
from .documents import UserTreeDocument

@celery.task(name="save_user_tree")
def save_user_tree():
    all_user_doc = UserTreeDocument.objects.only('user_id').all()
    for doc in all_user_doc:
        tree_info = orjson.loads(redis_tree.get(f"tree_{doc.user_id}"))
        doc.update(**tree_info)
```

The task runs correctly, but only have warning-code.
How can I fix the warning?

My English is not very good. Sorry if my description is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repair plan:
`MONGODB_CONNECT = False`

I have repaired this question by myself ~
The document say that:

By default flask-mongoengine open the connection when extension is instanciated but you can configure it to open connection only on first database access by setting the MONGODB_SETTINGS['connect'] parameter or its MONGODB_CONNECT flat equivalent to False